# How to get the php echo response in IOS after posting to the php script using swift

Tags: php, ios, swift

I am wondering in the ios app, how to get php echo response after posting to the php script using swift

Now, when i print the response out in the ios app, it shows lots of info, such as status code,header,content type, date. But i want neither of them

All i want is the ios app can return the php echo string `<?php echo 'You have successfully registered';?>`

SWIFT CODE

```
    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.swiftdeveloperblog.com/http-post-example-script/");

    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"// Compose a query string

    let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("response = \(response)")

        //Let's convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:
        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            if let parseJSON = json {

                // Now we can access value of First Name by its key
                let firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
                print("firstNameValue: \(firstNameValue)")
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php echo 'You have successfully registered';?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP code will output:

> You have successfully registered

Your Swift code just prints the whole response object (which contains alot of information), then your trying to parse the data as a JSON response, which it isn't, so it will fail.

What you need to do is to access the response data (which will be be output from the PHP code) and covert it to a string

```
if let data = data {
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(string) //JSONSerialization
}
```

Try putting this in your response handling section just after the error handling and this should show the response you expect.

Comment: hi, i have tried, but it fail to display the php echo, it only display the word string,any idea? Many thanks.